# Do I need to prepare old pipe to install a compression fitting?

Tags: plumbing, toilet, shutoff

I bought a new multi-turn valve to replace a really old one.

[image]

The new one has a compression fitting where the old one is soldered. My plan is to use a pipe cutter just below the soldered joint. I'm not soldering or using sharkbite hardware. Here's a pic:

[image]

Do I need to prepare the surface of the pipe where the new compression fitting will be sitting to avoid a leak?

Comment: I would heartily recommend returning that (new multi-turn) and getting a 1/4 turn shutoff - they are very good for the job and have far fewer problems from old age.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, the ring compression should work just fine. They don't look it, but they were standard long before the push-fittings came along and made this stupid easy. As long as there's nothing under the ring, it should seal properly.

I would get a wheel-type cutter to do this, however. Not only will it not burr the pipe, but it won't bend it either.